# Loading PyTorch model in multiprocessing Process flashes cmd

Tags: python, command-line, multiprocessing, pytorch

## Problem:

When I open pytorch model (read as *load state_dict from disk*) in subprocess it pops up cmd window for couple ms which causes other programs to loose focus - annoying when working on something else etc.
I have traced the cause to 2 lines, both causing it in some circumstances and managed to reproduce it for one (the second one is when doing `model.to(device)`)

#### main.py

```py
model_path = 'testing\\agent\\model_test.pth'

# create model
from testing.agent.torch_model import Net
import torch
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu") # I have cuda available
m = Net()
m.to(device)
# save it
torch.save(m.state_dict(), model_path)

# open it in subprocess
from testing.agent.AgentOpenSim_Process import Open_Agent_Sim
p = Open_Agent_Sim(p=model_path, msgLogger=None)
p.start()
```

#### torch_model.py

(source pydocs: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/save_load_across_devices.html)

```py
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.functional as F

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

#### AgentOpenSim_Process.py

```py
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
import os, time, torch

from testing.agent.torch_model import Net


class Open_Agent_Sim(Process): 
    def __init__(self, p:str, **kwargs):          
        super(Process, self).__init__(daemon=True)
        self.path = p
        self._msgLogger = kwargs['msgLogger'] if kwargs['msgLogger'] is not None else Queue() 
        self.device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        self.device_cpu = torch.device("cpu")

    def __print(self, msg: str, verbosity):
        # personal tool for debugging multiprocessing (it sends messages to Queue and main process 
        # reads them inside thread and prints into console... and yes i know about multiprocessing 
        # logger, its used aswell)
        self._msgLogger.put(('Open_Agent_Sim: '+msg, verbosity)) 

    def run(self):
        self.__pid = os.getpid()
        try:
            self.__print('opening model',0)
            self.init_agent()
            self.__print('opening model - done',0)
        except Exception as e:           
            # solved by custom exception wrapper
            pass
        else:            
            self.__print('has ended',0)
            return

    def init_agent(self):
        # init instance
        self.__print('0a', 0) 
        m = Net()    
        self.__print('0b', 0)  
        time.sleep(2)
        # load state dict
        self.__print('1a', 0)        
        l = torch.load(self.path, map_location=self.device_cpu)
        self.__print('1b', 0)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.__print('2a', 0)
        m.load_state_dict(l)
        # set to device
        self.__print('2b', 0)   
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            self.__print('3a', 0)
            m.to(self.device) # ----> This line pops up cmd
            self.__print('3b', 0)             
        except RuntimeError as e:
            self.__print(str(e), 0)
```

When visually debugging those cmd pops up, its always in step 1 (`m.load_state_dict(torch.load(self.path, map_location=self.device))`)

I have tried something like disabling console output which didnt work.

```py
import contextlib
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
    ...
```

The `if __name__=='__main__':` makes no difference and also this is all part of heavy multiprocessing in some lower subprocess

## Update

I traced problem to switching device - if I use `torch.load(self.path, map_location=self.device_cpu)` and later `.to(self.device_gpu)` it pops cmd on line with `.to(...)` but if I use `torch.load(self.path, map_location=self.device_gpu)` it pops on that line. Another thing to note is, that it does not matter on which device model is saved.

I am open to any workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating pytorch version by install command from their website solved the issue